# unable to parse SAML token in SAML 2.0 login with firebase and authentik

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, saml, saml-2.0

I am developing an application in ReactJS which is SSO enabled; application is integrated with FireBase (as a service provider) and Authentik (as an idP) for SAML 2.0 enabled for SSO.
In the process, on user login SSO process is initiated from FireBase; I can see a valid and successful SAML response with valid values. However, on the UI I see the error " Firebase: Unable to parse the SAML token. (auth/invalid-credential).  ".

Does anyone suggest what could be the possible cause for this error?

For the reference; here's the snapshot of the user sign in code --

```
import { LOGOUT,LOGGEDIN, ISSIGNIN, _debug } from '../../constants';
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import compatApp from "firebase/compat/app";

import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { Button } from '@mui/material';

import { borrowerGetUserData } from "../../actions/borrower";

import { getAuth, signOut, GoogleAuthProvider, FacebookAuthProvider,EmailAuthProvider,PhoneAuthProvider, SAMLAuthProvider, signInWithPopup, linkWithPopup, signInWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";
import {  mongoborrowerGetUserData, mongoborrowerGetFinanceData } from '../../actions/borrower';
import { mongoborrowerPostUserData } from '../../actions/borrower';
import { getIdToken} from "firebase/auth";



var app
const firebaseConfig = _debug === 'development' 
    ?{
      apiKey            : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_API_KEY_UAT,
      authDomain        : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_DOMAIN_UAT,
      projectId         : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_PROJECTID_UAT,
      storageBucket     : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_BUCKET_UAT,
      messagingSenderId : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_MSG_SNDR_ID_UAT,
      appId             : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_APP_ID_UAT,
      measurementId     : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_MSRMT_ID_UAT,
      loglevel          : process.env.CONFIG_LOG_LEVEL
    }
    :{
        apiKey            : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_API_KEY,
        authDomain        : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
        projectId         : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_PROJECTID,
        storageBucket     : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_MSG_SNDR_ID,
        appId             : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_APP_ID,
        measurementId     : process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_AUTH_MSRMT_ID,
        loglevel          : process.env.CONFIG_LOG_LEVEL
    };  
try {
  app = compatApp.app();
} catch (error) {
  app = compatApp.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
const auth = compatApp.auth(app);

function SignInScreen() {

    const { bProfile,bProfileStatus } = useSelector((state)=>state.borrower); 
    const { bfinancialProfile } = useSelector((state)=>state.borrower);
    const [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(false); // Local signed-in state.
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    
    console.log('location',location);
    const provider = new SAMLAuthProvider('saml.authentik-nf');
    console.log('provider',provider);
    
    const uiConfig = {
        signInFlow: 'popup',
        signInOptions: [
          provider.providerId 
        ],
        callbacks: {
          
          signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async function(authResult, redirectUrl="/DashboardProfile") {
           const token= await getIdToken(user,true); 
          sessionStorage.setItem('authToken', token);

            var email = (user.multiFactor.user.email) ? user.multiFactor.user.email : bProfile.emailId;
            var mno =  (user.multiFactor.user.phoneNumber) ? user.multiFactor.user.phoneNumber : bProfile.phoneNumber;
            console.log("get token from session storage",sessionStorage.getItem('authToken'));
          // send either email or phone number for new user registration
          if(user.multiFactor.user.email){
            var apiBodyData = {
              "data":{
              "isBorrower":true,
              "emailId": email,
              }
            }
          }else if(user.multiFactor.user.phoneNumber){
            var apiBodyData = {
              "data":{
              "isBorrower":true,
              "phoneNumber": mno,
              }
            }
          }
          console.log("apiBodyData",apiBodyData)
          dispatch(mongoborrowerPostUserData(apiBodyData));

            dispatch(mongoborrowerGetUserData(bProfile)); 
            dispatch(mongoborrowerGetFinanceData(bfinancialProfile));
            return true;
          },

        },
      };
      
    const logout = () => {
        auth.signOut()
        dispatch({ type: LOGOUT })
        navigate("/", { replace: true });
    };
    
      // Listen to the Firebase Auth state and set the local state.
    useEffect(() => {
      const unregisterAuthObserver = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        setIsSignedIn(!!user);
        user === null ? dispatch({ type: LOGOUT }) : dispatch({ type: LOGGEDIN });
      });
        return () => unregisterAuthObserver(); // Make sure we un-register Firebase observers when the component unmounts.
    }, []);
    
      if (!isSignedIn) {
        return (
          <div><StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={auth} /></div>
        );
      }

      return (
        <div>
          <p>Welcome {auth.currentUser.displayName}! You are now signed-in!</p>
          {/* <a onClick={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>Sign-out</a> */}
          {/* <a onClick={logout}>Sign-out</a> */}
    
          <Button variant="contained" sx={{p:'0.5vw', width:'8vw',ml:'.5vw',width:'6vw',fontSize:'0.7vw',backgroundColor:'#31312C',color:'#FFFFFF', "&.MuiButtonBase-root:hover": {
              backgroundColor:'#31312C',color:'#FFFFFF'
              } }} onClick={logout}>Sign-out</Button>
          
        </div>
      );
}

export default SignInScreen;
```

any other method or way to solve the issue